# (object[,])range.get_Value(XL.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault) causes a conversion error

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, excel-interop

**Error:**

`Cannot convert type 'string' to 'object[*,*]'`

That's the error I have been getting. Can someone give me some pointers so that I can avoid it? Thanks.

**Note:**

Interestingly, `(object[,])range.get_Value(XL.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)`

will only produce this bug when `range.Count == 1`. It works fine when count is equal to and above 2.

**sample code:**

```
object[,] arrValue;  //global variable

private string[] createFormulaCollection()
        {
            ArrayList s = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                //look at the currently active excel sheet
                //iterate through cells (not Null) and find the one contains IES(...)
                //save it into the arraylist
                //use dictionary to save position and value (position as key)
                workbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
                worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
                range = worksheet.UsedRange;

                MessageBox.Show(range.Count.ToString());


                if (range.Count > 1)
                {
                    //need to make sure there are at least 2 "ies" cells before converting to object[,]
                    arrValue = (object[,])range.get_Value(XL.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault); 
                }
                else
                {
                    arrValue[1,1] = range.get_Value(XL.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault); //my try here. seems still got problem though.
                }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return (string[])s.ToArray(typeof(string));
        }
```

Comment: It makes good sense that the error only occurs when range.Count == 1, since the Range is then referring to a specific cell, and get_Value returns the value of that cell.

Comment: However, the error you mentioned shouldn't occur in the code you posted, since you are specifically handling the case where range.Count == 1.

Comment: Yeah, that's just my attempt. I wanna capture the specific case where range.Count == 1 so it wouldn't throw exception unintentionally. But my approach above isn't quite right, since you are doing string -> object array conversion.

Comment: I don't follow. If arrValue has been instantiated when you assign to arrValue[1,1], there shouldn't be a problem from what I can gather from the code you've posted. So what exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Bernhof because the type of the return value from range.get_Value() did not match the one of arrValue[1,1] for some reason. Do you think it's correct if we do, `object[,] arrValue = range.get_Value(XL.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault); ` ? I guess not.

Comment: Nope, it's not correct if range.Count == 1. But you've already handled that situation. Since it is an object array, you can place any value inside it, i.e. the `arrValue[1,1] = range.get_Value(...)` shouldn't fail. It just seems that you've already solved the problem that you are asking us to help you with...?

Comment: @Bernhof you are correct. `arrValue[1,1] = range.get_Value(...)` shouldn't fail as long as arrValue object array is instantiated. Man, I guess I did solve it by myself but my mind was still playing tricks on me. lol Anyway, thanks very much for all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding:

`range.get_Value(XL.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);` will return a string when range.Count == 1
which means it can't be converted to object[,] type.

it can, however, when range.Count > 1.

My workaround:

Just deal with it separately. So in my case I had to first count the number of range object and process them accordingly.

```
if(range.Count > 1)
{
    //code...
}
else
{
    string singleStrValue = range.get_Value(XL.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
    int iRow, iCol;
    iRow = range.Row;
    iCol = range.Column;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(singleStrValue))
    {
        //code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with

```
(object[,])range.get_Value(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Comment: for what arrValue is global? where is range defined? why you are accessing in the else scope the array with index 1,1 and not 0,0 ? did you do a step-by-step debugging? if yes, in which line it's crashing?

Comment: The index can't start from 0,0, because of the way range.get_Value() returns its value. Plus the class is really huge and I m not possible to post all the code in here.

Comment: the code will crash when range.count == 1, as said clearly in the question post. so it failed in the else block. Originally I didn't even put if...else..., this is just for debugging and trying a few possible approaches.