# How do I load all the data from an excel file into a C# textbox?

Tags: c#, excel, loops

So I'm trying to open an excel file and populate a textbox with all the values in the spreadsheet. Whenever I run my code it puts the value from cell A1 but that's it. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong with my loops. Please help and thank you in advance.

```
private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog loadFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (loadFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string rowsAndColumns = "";
                fileName = loadFile.FileName;
                Excel.Application myApp = new Excel.Application();
                myApp.Visible = false;
                Excel.Workbook myBook = myApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
                Excel.Worksheet mySheet = myBook.Sheets[1];

                object[,] words = (object[,])mySheet.UsedRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);


                for (int row = 1; row <= mySheet.UsedRange.Row; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 1; column <= mySheet.UsedRange.Column; column++)
                    {
                        rowsAndColumns += words[row, column];
                    }
                    rowsAndColumns += Environment.NewLine;
                }
                BasicTextBox.Text = rowsAndColumns;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just two little suggestions: 
(1) use `StringBuilder` class to build Your string instead of concatenating with `+`. (2) make sure You can avoid error when there is only one cell in the range (issue described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383304/object-range-get-valuexl-xlrangevaluedatatype-xlrangevaluedefault-causes-a).
I know that this is not an answer to Your question, but it still may be helpful ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= mySheet.UsedRange.Row.Count; row++)
```

and

```
for (int column = 1; column <= mySheet.UsedRange.Column.Count; column++)
```

and

```
rowsAndColumns += words[row, column].ToString();
```

Comment: For some reason Count gave me an error so I used mySheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Column and that seemed to work. Thank you for the tip though